# How to disable configuration display at nvim startup?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

When typing nvim  in CLI, nvim opens with a screen that contains all my configurations (the picture bellow).

I have to press <s-g> and then hit Enter in order to open the file i wanted.

The same happens when i'm sourcing vim.init (:source $MYVIMRC).

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. What's this screen?
2. How can I disable it?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It looks like this is happening because you have a bare `au` (to display all autocmd's) rather than an `au!` (to clear all autocmd's for an augroup). If you can show or share your init.vim we can probably point to where the bug is...

Comment: thank you! found it, it was an auto (without anything else) outside of an augroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing in that output is a list of all defined auto-commands.

You get Vim/NeoVim to list all defined auto-commands with the Ex command `autocmd` with no arguments. This command can be abbreviated to simply `au` or `auto`. So in order to have Vim/NeoVim display all defined auto-commands at startup, you probably have an `auto` in your vimrc or `init.vim` (which you confirmed in your comments.)

Note that it's quite common to use `autocmd!` (with a bang) inside an `augroup` as its first command, in order to clear the `augroup` of any commands previously defined inside it, before adding new command definitions there. This is useful in case you reload the Vim script (such as your vimrc or `init.vim`), to prevent the auto-commands from getting duplicated as they get defined again every time the file is sourced.

The pattern goes like:

```
augroup NameOfGroup
  autocmd!
  ... autocmd definitions ...
augroup END
```

So I imagine you were missing the `!` in the `autocmd!` in the beginning of one of the `augroup`s... You can fix it by adding the missing `!` there.